# Send application sound to a specific audio device C#

Tags: c#, windows, audio

Is there a possible way to make an application send sound to a specific sound device?

For example:

I have a computer with its own speakers, and two HDMI TV.  Have 3 Google Chrome windows and they have their own sounds, but I want that one window play his sounds on one HDMI device, the other window on the other HDMI device, and the other window in the PC.

I have been looking for some libraries but they only allow to play sounds on a specific device not to listen to an application.

Comment: This is going to be entirely platform-specific. Please specify a platform. (I'm guessing Windows, but it is hard to tell)

Comment: @DarkFalcon, that's correct. In Windows using C#. Is like the CheVolume application.

Comment: I have sucessfully worked with [libZPlay](http://libzplay.sourceforge.net/WELCOME.html) and used its `EnumerateWaveOut` and `SetWaveOutDevice` methods.

Comment: See VB-Audio Virtual Cable or Virtual Audio Cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to affect existing application behavior, then your question is for SuperUser rather than StackOverflow.

If you are interested in achieving mentioned in code, programmatically, then your app can certainly do it. Any Windows audio API has output device enumeration functions and selection of device to output to. Many apps just pick default device without taking a trouble to choose among existing ones. That is, the application itself needs to be capable of choosing specific audio output device, it's not something user sets up externally: Control Panel only allows to select default audio output device, system wide.